# Unsafe region of code in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Sometimes it is hard to come up with valid TypeScript, for example when you reference a library that has tons of entities each of which needs its declaration. In situations like this it would be nice to tell TypeScript to skip a part of code that deals with that library considering it valid. So is there a way to do that in TypeScript?

Answer (score 14):

There isn't a way to turn off type checking for an entire block of code, but if you access anything off an expression of type `any`, the result will also be `any`, so if you can access the library through an `any` reference of any sort, you'll effectively be working without type checking.

Comment: Why the down-vote? This looks correct to me... You simply use `declare var MyLib: any;` and TypeScript allows you to call any property or function you like on `MyLib`. Therefore, +1 from me.

Comment: Unfortunately you completely disable typechecking for that entity then. Often, you only want an isolated statement to be unchecked. Would be nice to have something like that.

Answer (score 10):

Put `// @ts-ignore` above the line with an error

```
 // @ts-ignore
 null.toString()
```